# When are category pages updated in MoinMoin?

Tags: wiki, moinmoin

I have edited a lot of pages in my Wiki—which uses [MoinMoin](https://moinmo.in)—yesterday. Most of them belong to a specific category. I have assigned those pages to the existing category.

The following happens:

- When displayed in the preview, it shows all 19 pages belonging to the category.
- When displayed regularly, it shows only 14 pages.

I assume this is related to the cache, since I see

```
<<FullSearchCached(category:CategoryTest)>>
```

Therefore I have two questions:

1. When does MoinMoin update the category pages?
2. How could I force updating the category pages?

I have tried:

- Other pages in the same category are shown, so it’s not a problem of the category page itself. I have also checked the category link on the pages.
- Restarting the MoinMoin server.
- Waiting until today.

Comment: @JakeGould: on Stack Overflow it is not recommended to use tags in titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an up to date category page, either use

```
<<FullSearch(category:CategoryTest)>>
```

instead of

```
<<FullSearchCached(text)>>`
```

(see [here](https://moinmo.in/HelpOnMacros))

Or you have to delete the cache (Dropdownmenue at the Top of the wiki) after you put in a new Site to the category so you can reload the categorypage to update the result.